# How do I avoid first ssh client hanging when using shared ssh connections

Tags: ssh, git

Theres plenty of examples on the web of how to use connection sharing:

```
ControlMaster auto
ControlPath ~/.ssh/sockets/%r@%h-%p
ControlPersist 600
```

However, I've found that the very first ssh connection (this is using git if that is relevant) hangs at an odd place (during exit I believe) - any attempt to `pstack` the git process or even `kill -9` it do nothing at all. All that works is to kill the calling process.

However, it appears the ssh connection socket has been set up (there is now an ssh process running which ps shows as `ssh: /home/ttanner/.ssh/sockets/user@host-22 [mux]`) and subsequent sshs appear to work fine.

This is quite annoying as git seems to spend quite some time fiddling with ssh connections and we'd really like to use this in our CI system - when we don't know on which machine we're going to running any particular bunch of git commands and so hanging on the 1st connection isn't a good option

Addendum: Running with debug on shows this odd message:

```
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
```

which possibly means that the sharing isn't actually working at all, it's just that in the subsequent connections git doesn't care and is using local information.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I'm facing the same problem on a Mac OSX.

Comment: not really. It just magically stopped going wrong